# Boat wiring mystery puzzle

Tags: wiring, 12v

First post, please forgive any errors.

Our dear father passed away leaving us his boat. The owner before had made some changes to the wiring (not for the better) leaving a tangle of loose ends and disconnected components. 
One puzzle is the navigation lights. These 5 x 12v bulbs are turned on by 2 switches (1 anchor light, 4 steaming lights). The control panel features 5 LEDs to act as indicators (of some sort).
Currently everything is disconnected and I wish to restore function. I can see how to make the switches turn on the nav lights. But what of the LEDs (which appear to have resistors in series with them so they may be driven by 12v)? And what role is played by the 2 x 1N5408 diodes soldered in series? 
Should the LEDs be wired so as to simply indicate that the lights are powered or is there a design such that a LED will go off if the nav light bulb fails?
Any help will be much appreciated.
The elements in the scheme:

[image: elements]

The photos of the panel and backplate (featuring, oddly, 2 diodes wired in series with the anchor nav light) give some clues, suggesting the same scheme is repeated 5 times for the 5 nav lights and corresponding LEDs. Note the "neutrals" of the Nav Lights are not obviously available being some feet away in the boat.

[image: front panel]

[image: back panel]

[image: Backplate]

Thankyou

Comment: *Should the LEDs be wired so as to simply indicate that the lights are powered or is there a design such that a LED will go off if the nav light bulb fails?* This is purely down to you and whatever boat regulations might dictate. You decide.

Comment: Best guess (not an answer) is that "12V" is somewhere above 12V with the motor running and charging, and the series 5408s reduce the voltage to prolong nav bulb life. LED/R across the bulb to show it's powered. Nothing more complex than that.

Comment: Thanks Andy, yes your right of course. But I am not sure how in either eventuality these components should go together.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that sounds very convincing. The alternators raise 12v to 14.4v when running, so your "over voltage" protection hypothesis may well be right. Thankyou.

Comment: When you work it out, draw the schematic, number the connections on the "chocolate block" strips and laminate the drawing. It should be cable tied to one of the wires behind the panel.

Comment: Pedantic point: it’s only the forward-facing white light halfway up the mast which is properly the “steaming” light, indicating a power vessel. The stern, starboard and port lights are “navigation” lights. On a power vessel they can be switched together so it’s an academic distinction, but on a sailboat the steaming light has to be switched separately, to show when the motor’s running.

Comment: I would not call those diodes "over voltage" protection because anything that is designed to connect to the _nominally_ "12V" electrical system of a boat or a motor vehicle is designed to withstand the 14.whatever Volts present when the engine is running. I would simply say what @BrianDrummond said---that the diodes are there to prolong the life of the lamps.